# AngularJS add/remove item from dynamic object

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, angularjs

Currently I have problem with adding/removing content dynamically from my application.

Scenario: I have few buttons in each row of table. After click on specified button, its value + typename should be visible on list below table. Button should also get active-class.

On the other hand, click on ACTIVE button should remove specified item from list and should also remove active-class.

My idea of adding elements was to create empty itemsArray = [] and push into that array details about clicked elements. PS. I can click all buttons from all rows so all can be active.

Question: how to remove specified item? On what should I iterate ? Buttons in first row have indexes equal to 1,2,3...
Buttons in second row have indexes equal to 1,2,3... and all rows have the same.

Splice won't work because script doesn't know which index=1, index=2 should remove.

```
<tr ng-repeat="score in scores" ng-class-odd="'odd-row'" ng-class-even="'even-row'">
  <td class="time">{{score.time}}</td>
  <td class="result">{{score.result}}</td>
  <td class="match-odds">
    <a class="default-btn" ng-repeat="match_odd in score.match_odds">{{match_odd.value}}</a>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Posting your controller code and also a sample of the JSON from your scores object would help you get a better answer.

Comment: Just like @MikeFeltman said, please post more of your code so we can give you a better answer. Also, if you can't use splice with your array, then you should change it so you can do so.